# What is the value of the series $1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

How can we evaluate $1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$?

Comment: Fourier series is useful to evaluate this series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Taylor series of $\log\left(1+x\right)
 $ is $$\log\left(1+x\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n},-1<x\leq1
 $$ so $$1+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n}=\color{red}{1-\frac{\log\left(2\right)}{2}}.$$

Comment: Is the power series continuous only inside the interval of convergece or is the power series continuous at $1$ too? I think there is a result that states that the power series is continuous inside the interval of convergence, but I am not sure about the endpoints.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb *only* inside the convergence interval *in general* , **but in this case** it is also continuous from the left at $\;x=1\;$ . See Abel's theorem.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb See what DonAntonio wrote :D

Answer (score 4):

Using the well known alternating harmonic series' sum :

$$\log2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\implies 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}=1-\frac12\log2=1-\log\sqrt2$$

One way to get the sum of that alternating series:

$$|x|<1\implies\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n\stackrel{integ.}\implies\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

and now check the last series **does converge also** for $\;x=1\;$, and you could then also use Abel's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

By the geometric summation formula, for $-1<x<1$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-x)^{k-1}=\frac1{1+x}.$$

Then integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}k=\log(1+x).$$

This is just a hint to evaluate your sum, as termwise integration and convergence of the series at $x=1$ must be justified.

Comment: Explanation required for the downvote.

Comment: I also was downvoted...pretty usual in this site.

Comment: Who wants to chair the club of the victims of mysterious downvoters ?